# heroku pgbackups:restore not working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When I run `heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL x123 --confirm app_name`
Everything seems to go smoothly in the console but the DB remains empy.

HELP!

Comment: Sounds like an issue for Heroku support.  Check your logs too: `heroku logs`.

Comment: heroku-postgres dataclips showed that the data is actually there.

Comment: some bug on postgres.heroku.com I guess.

Comment: how are you seeing that the db is empty? is via `heroku pg:info`, that info is cached, hence often outdated.

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: @Herokiller yes but I can't remember how. I think it was some platform issue of the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database stats such as table count are populated in the background. For the Starter tier that can be delayed by a few minutes. As @kch mentioned as well, there's some caching involved.

Stats for Production tier are updated more frequently, typically less than 1 minute.

Comment: after some time my db is still empty, while logs say restore was success